# How to use Zxing for qr code scanner without using camera?

Tags: android, barcode, zxing, qr-code

How can I read a QR Code from the screen without using camera in Android Developing Tools by using **ZXing library** ? 
Please can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: how you want read qr ?